# Trying to access JSON data through an API

Tags: node.js, api, npm, request

I am using node request to access data on an api.  Now when I use the following code to access the body I get the following response.

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){

//var series = req.body.series;
var circuits = req.body.Circuits;
var url = req.body.url

request("http://ergast.com/api/f1/circuits/" + circuits + ".json", function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
    res.write("<p>Here is the information about the circuit " + circuits + " in the " + url + " is about the circuit </p>")
  });
})
```

and I get the following response from the Api.

```
{
"MRData": {
    "xmlns": "http://ergast.com/mrd/1.4",
    "series": "f1",
    "url": "http://ergast.com/api/f1/circuits/brands_hatch.json",
    "limit": "30",
    "offset": "0",
    "total": "1",
    "CircuitTable": {
        "circuitId": "brands_hatch",
        "Circuits": [
            {
                "circuitId": "brands_hatch",
                "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brands_Hatch",
                "circuitName": "Brands Hatch",
                "Location": {
                    "lat": "51.3569",
                    "long": "0.263056",
                    "locality": "Kent",
                    "country": "UK"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

Now the question is that I need to access the properties.  Like for instance, the url gives me an error of undefined in the paragraph tag.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: body.MRData.url doesn't work?

Comment: @Pedro Silva That does not work.  It still gives me undefined!

Comment: Check the typeof body like, console.log(typeof body), if it's string that you should use JSON.parse(body).MRData.url, if not I really can't understand your problem.

Comment: I am trying to access url or any of the properties in Circuits:[] .  This is the response I am getting. `TypeError: Cannot read property 'CircuitTable' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your console.log it should be

```
console.log(JSON.parse(body));
```

Or

```
var bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
var yourUrl = bodyParsed.MRData.url
```

As I said in the comments, your body is a string, console.log(typeof body) returns string, so it needs to be parsed to an object with properties.

Comment: Suppose I wanted to access the url in this part of the json data `"Circuits": [
            {
                "circuitId": "brands_hatch",
                "url": "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brands_Hatch",
                "circuitName": "Brands Hatch",
                "Location": {
                    "lat": "51.3569",
                    "long": "0.263056",
                    "locality": "Kent",
                    "country": "UK"
                }`

Comment: bodyParsed.MRData.CircuitTable should work like you requested.

Comment: var request = require('request');

 request('http://ergast.com/api/f1/circuits/brands_hatch.json', function (error, response, body) {

  var bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body)
     console.log(bodyParsed.MRData.CircuitTable); 
 });
That's my code, and it works like a charm, I don't understand how it can't work with you.

Comment: this is what I get with my paragraph tags Here is the information about the circuit aintree in the [object Object] series. `res.write("<p>Here is the information about the circuit " + circuits + " in the " + yourUrl + " series </p>")`

Comment: You have to do JSON.stringify(bodyParsed.MRData.CircuitTable) on your res.write. otherwise, it's impossible to convert from object to string.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185949/discussion-between-altbrian-and-pedro-silva).